# static map api "Invalid or nonexistent map configuration token "

Tags: carto, static

Im trying to create static map and im having problem:

> Invalid or nonexistent map configuration token

When I publish map I get two links and they work fine with token in link https://rokiszb.carto.com/builder/ec62c84b-c6ec-41b3-9468-353b608c88fe/embed . But this token doesnt work for my static map link https://rokiszb.carto.com/api/v1/map/static/center/ec62c84b-c6ec-41b3-9468-353b608c88fe/10/54.1/24.1/1500/1500.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking the `viz.json` with the `layergroupid`. The former is the one you need to add to your API call. You can get it using your browser network tab:

[image: layergroupid]

I have also replaced the output to `.png` format because it looks like there is an issue related to `.jpg`:

https://rokiszb.carto.com/api/v1/map/static/center/rokiszb@ce5812c4@b8dcf7853dac0322cd8ca40d9a4ea4eb:1507746854337/10/54.1/24.1/1500/1500.jpg

[image: static-maps-api]